# Using multiple Jedis clusters for caching with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I have 2 jedis caches:

- localhost:6379
- cache.servermachine.com:6380,password=abcdef

Where one redis instance is hosted locally, and one on a secured machine with a password. I have a Spring Boot configuration class.

```
public class RedisCacheConfig {
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    return new JedisConnectionFactory();
}

@Bean
RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate());
}
}
```

In my `application.yml` file, how do I modify the `spring.redis.cluster` options to have multiple nodes, one with password?

I am using Jedis 1.9.0.

Comment: Jedis doesn't have version 1.9.0. Maybe 2.9.0?

Answer (score 1):

You can create as many connection factories as you need, using them to create multiple `RedisTemplate` beans and then multiple `CacheManager` beans:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class RedisCacheConfiguration {

    public static class RedisProperties {
        @NotNull @Size(min = 1) private List<String> nodes;
        @NotNull private String password;
        // getters and setters omitted 
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.redis.clusters")
    @Validated
    public static class MultipleRedisProperties {
        @NotNull @Valid private RedisProperties local;
        @NotNull @Valid private RedisProperties remote;
        // getters and setters omitted 
    }

    @Bean MultipleRedisProperties multipleRedisProperties() { 
        return new MultipleRedisProperties (); 
    }

    @Bean JedisConnectionFactory localJedisCF() {
        RedisClusterConfiguration clusterCfg = new RedisClusterConfiguration(redisProperties().getLocal().getNodes());
        JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory(clusterCfg );
        factory.setPassword(redisProperties().getPassword());
        factory.setUsePool(true);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean RedisTemplate<Object, Object> localRedisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(localJedisCF());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean CacheManager localJedisCacheManager() { 
        new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate()); 
    }

    // similar bean definitions for the remote cluster omitted
}
```

Then, with your configuration as follows (example in YAML):

```
spring.redis.clusters:
  local:
    nodes: localhost:6379
    password:
  remote:
    nodes: cache.servermachine.com:6380
    password: abcdef
```

you can use the created cache managers with cache abstractions:

```
@Cacheable(key = "#name", cacheManager = "localRedisCacheManager")
public String greet(@PathVariable String name) {
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

If you are using Spring Data Redis, you may have to exclude the following auto-configurations if they get in the way: `RedisAutoConfiguration`,`RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration`