# How to use Cacheable annotation in spring boot app when it already uses jedis as a fast storage

Tags: java, spring, caching, jedis

I'm working on java spring project (Spring Boot v2.3.3.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.8.RELEASE).

I'm want to use spring's @Cacheable annotation with customized cache (not spring default cache).
I already have Jedis configured in this app to be used as fast storage.
In order to use this annotation I need to configure cacheManger,
but I'm not sure how to implement it so it will make use with Jedis, all I find is Redis.

any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48181614/using-multiple-jedis-clusters-for-caching-with-spring-boot) on setting up `CacheManager -> RedisCacheManager -> RedisTemplate -> JedisConnectionFactory -> Redis(Cluster/Standalone)Configuration + JedisClientConfiguration`

Think RedisStandalone Configuration best suits your needs:

> Configuration class used for setting up RedisConnection via
> RedisConnectionFactory using connecting to a single node Redis
> installation.

There is no JedisCachemanager, only a RedisCacheManager like you said, therefore you have to setup a RedisTemplate with a JedisConnectionFactory: `redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(getJedisConnectionFactory())`, then you can setup the `jedisConnectionFactory` with your specific configs e.g. setting database index name, redis host name, JedisClientConfiguration, timeouts, etc. See [JedisConnectionFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory.html)

Example setup of the JedisConnectionFactory setup

```
  redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(getJedisConnectionFactory())

  private JedisConnectionFactory getJedisConnectionFactory() {      
      JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new 
JedisConnectionFactory();      
      jedisConnectionFactory.setClientName("myClientName");      
      jedisConnectionFactory.set(new JedisClientConfiguration(
        new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(...), 
        new JedisClientConfiguration(...)))
```

Comment: Hey, can you please explain?

Comment: Yea basically there is no JedisCachemanager, only a RedisCacheManager like you said, therefore you have to setup a RedisTemplate with a JedisConnectionFactory: `redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(getJedisConnectionFactory())`, then you can setup the jedisConnectionFactory bean with your specific configs e.g. setting database index name, redis host name, JedisClientConfiguration, timeouts, etc. See [JedisConnectionFactory here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/jedis/JedisConnectionFactory.html)

Comment: Example setup of the JedisConnectionFactory setup
`private JedisConnectionFactory getJedisConnectionFactory() {

    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory =
        new JedisConnectionFactory();

    jedisConnectionFactory.setClientName("myClientName");

    jedisConnectionFactory.set(new JedisClientConfiguration())`

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Do you know how can I use TLS with this? because I cant connect to redis, I guess this is what causing the connection problem.

Comment: np! Can you please approve my answer if it helped? A little convoluted now but Try [LettuceConnectionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454011/jedisconnectionfactory-that-can-handle-tls) which has TLS. Set [LettuceClientConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.1.0.RC2/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce/LettuceClientConfiguration.html) with TLS instead of SSL

Comment: Unfortunately no :( this api version is deprecated then the one im using. About the Lettuce, also tried it, Im having a problem with spring's redis healthCheck, it cant connect to redis server even though I can connect to it with jedis from same app. But I cant use jedis for the custom settings for the Cacheable annotation. Stuck on this :(

Comment: Hey Eric, you can improve your answer by incorporating your comments into the answer.

Comment: Hey CausingUnderflowsEverywhere updated answer thanks for suggestion

Comment: Issue is "JedisConnectionFactory that can handle TLS + Redis Health check failing due to inability to connect to the Jedis Connection Setup"

Jessi have you tried to configure Jedis with the RedisClientConfigurations? 
You can instantiate the JedisConnectionFactory with RedisConfigurations, See the multiple constructor signatures, maybe that could fix the connection issue and doesn't need TLS?

1) JedisConnectionFactory(RedisStandaloneConfiguration standaloneConfig)
2) JedisConnectionFactory(RedisClusterConfiguration clusterConfig, JedisClientConfiguration clientConfig)
3) etc.

Comment: Updated answer: `jedisConnectionFactory.set(new JedisClientConfiguration(
        new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(...), 
        new JedisClientConfiguration clientConfig(...)))`